# Samba treating "Data" directory as if it were called "data"

Tags: samba

I connect to a virtual Linux box (Debian) installed from my Mac running Sierra using Samba. I've got two directories on my Linux box, one called "Data" and the other called "data." When I navigate into "Data" from the Mac, it shows me the files in "data" instead. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In your smb.conf file, add/edit the line `case sensitive` to `yes`. This may interfere with windows compatibility however. See here for more details: https://serverfault.com/questions/70570/does-samba-work-well-with-windows-when-case-sensitive-names-are-enabled

SMB (the MS protocol SAMBA re-implements) uses case insensitive pathing (in fact its all converted to upper case if the path info is lower or mixed case) based on the rules for the older NetBIOS/NetBuei protocols.

Comment: This would be done on the Linux side? And I read elsewhere about someone who tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: on the Samba Server side, so yes, per your description, the debian box. Since you are using a mac, you may need to make a simmilar change to your mac samba client configuration. see here for some discussion on where it is located on macs: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akronlug/fc92ybJCuV4